# Good hashing function for US phone numbers?

Tags: hash

What would be a good hashing function for US phone numbers? Which is basically a 10 digit number? It seems to me that, a simplistic:

```
(p1 * (areaCode + p2 * exchangeCode) + extensionCode) % r;
```

where `p1` and `p2` are some prime numbers and 'r' is the reduced range, should be fast as well as have good hashing properties.

Comment: What requirements do you have? Why not just use a standard string hashing function?

Answer (score 1):

Why not try just the last digit and a 10-"slots" hash table? IMHO this should give a fairly uniform distribution.